# Phonegap ajax/php post not working

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I have been trying to POST data from input to PHP (which will write to the .json file) But I only end up getting 404 XHR errors in browser. **(SEE LATEST EDIT)**

Note: am using the Phonegap Desktop version instead the CLI

So far I have added all the security, access, allow-navigation into the config.xml.

**EDIT**: Updated the code below and after made the path to php file absolute and now I get a new error: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing)

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://192.168.170.2/php/wjson.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "titel=" + titel + "&notitie=" + notitie + "&datum=" + vandaag,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: onError

            });
```

PHP

```
    <?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  
  header("content-type: application/json");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

  if(!$_POST) exit;

  $titel = $_POST['titel'];
  $notitie = $_POST['notitie'];
  $datum = $_POST['datum'];

  $file = 'data/notities.json';

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),TRUE);

  $json[count($json)] = array("titel" => $titel, "notitie" => $notitie, "datum" => $datum);

  file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json,TRUE));

?>
```

config.xml

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0">
    <name>wrts</name>
    <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0x00000000" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
    <access origin="http://192.168.2.4*"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <access origin="content:///*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: This URL suggests that the device is posting to its self `"php/wjson.php"`. There should be an absolute URL in there.

Comment: So... is your path to php file correct? I think it should be absolute

Comment: @ Ohgodwhy - I assume this is what it should be? But it doesn't fix the issue. http://prntscr.com/98v0xa

Comment: Adding `../` is still not absolute. Where is wjson.php located?

Comment: I just made it absolute by http://prntscr.com/98zkmb but now I get a " Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" error that its missing in the php file but I'm certain its in the php file as you can see: http://prntscr.com/98zku4

Comment: If you are the one generating the json that you want to get, use jsonp instead. it will make your headaches dissapear, believe me

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your .htaccess file?

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```